# How to send json from an AngularJS client to backend

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm trying to make a form in angular that sends the answers as json to mysql database. I'm using a Django backend and gcloud mysql. Any tips of projects which this type of implementation or links to guide / documentation?

Currently to create accounts (adding to the mysql) a shell script is ran on directly to container running the app.

Comment: There are two three questions in one here. The first is what architecture could be used to submit a data from browser and store it in a database. The second is how to use AngularJS to submit a form to a backend. The third is how to build a REST API with Django and MySQL. Please clarify what you have already tried and probably split your question so that each part would be focused and useful.

Comment: Hey the question is the second one! From the backend I can send to mysql and those are done. And I've tried to find solutions but I cant find any guides and am completly lost on where to even start

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser standard Fetch API to communicate with backend. Start from Mozilla guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch .

Then the missing piece is how to collect form data in JSON format. Probably Angular (or whatever framework) has a library to handle forms, but the standard vanilla-js way is to:

1. attach event listener for the 'submit' event of the form.
2. inside the event listener use the form (the event's target) to create an instance of `FormData` object. `const formData = new FormData(submitEvent.target);`
3. convert the created FormData instance into an object, which can be sent with FetchAPI as JSON: `Object.fromEntries(formData);`

You can find examples of form handling here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

JSON is not the only option, though. Django should know how to parse multipart form data or url-encoded form data as well. So, when you get hand of a `FormData` object - you can choose in which format to send. Whatever format is accepted by the backend.